Are Python's set[int] add/remove operations thread-safe?
Is the following Python code thread-safe? More precisely, under what conditions (Python implementations, versions, GIL presence, etc) is it guaranteed that KeyError will never happen and every item will be removed from the set at some point?
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import count


def worker(data: set[int], i: int):
    data.remove(i)


def main():
    data: set[int] = set()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for i in count():
            data.add(i)
            executor.submit(worker, data, i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I found a lot of contradictory information on the internet so I kindly ask any answers to be provided with sources, preferably Python official ones.

Likely relevant: Are Python built-in containers thread-safe?

The waters are muddy. Use a lock
